# How can i bring gridlines to the front?

Tags: d3.js

In d3 graphs, how can i bring gridlines to the front or back of the bars. Which parameter is responsible for the same?

[Sample working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/temirov/Rt65L/1/)

The code for ticks is:-

```
 var yAxisGrid = yAxis.ticks(numberOfTicks)
.tickSize(w, 0)
.tickFormat("")
.orient("right");
```

Comment: Where are the bars?

Comment: It has circles, you can increase their radius and see the grid lines falling back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing similar to the *z index* (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) in SVG.

So, your question:

> Which parameter is responsible for the same?

Has the answer: *none*.

That being said, this is the rule: who's painted later remains on top (just like a real painter using ink in a canvas).

So, just move the code for the circles to be before the code for the gridline.

```
//create the circles
svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("circle")
/)...

//draw axes here
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis") //assign "axis" class
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
.call(xAxis);
//...
```

This is your updated fiddle (I made the circles larger): http://jsfiddle.net/e4L7sn37/

Comment: In this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rBfy5/2218/ i have added gridlines first then the rectangles,still grid lines are coming on top

Comment: I had tried the same earlier but it wasnot showing up. I now see that i had done  " svg.selectAll('g') " instead of " svg.selectAll('.g') "  and so it was showing no rects just grid lines. Thank you for your patience though :)

Comment: The important thing here is the order of the groups. And selecting a previously existent group changes the enter selection.